# Setting max and mid date in date picker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Im trying to set max day which is the present day and the min year which is 20 years back. how can set this on my date picker?

heres the code on picking date

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        year=myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        updateLabel();
    }
};
pet_bday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pet_name.clearFocus();
        new DatePickerDialog(register_pet.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});
```

im using an edittext field to show the date picker. can anyone explain or show to me how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

Set max date to today.

```
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Set min date

```
Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, -20); //You are setting past 20 years.
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());
```